# For-Statement, Each 1000th Walkthrough, do something

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm walking through a Forloop 100'000 times. (that number can be diversified)

Every 1000th time I want do something specially, what I don't do in the other walkthroughs.

Something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    doTasks(); //Normal
    if(i == 1000 || i == 2000 || i == 3000 || i == 4000 ) //and so on...
    {
       doSomethingElse(); //Special, For every 1000th walkthrough
    }
}
```

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish that task?

Comment: does the 'i' is used in doTasks() or doSomethingElse()?

Comment: no, the answer is already answered, forgot about that operation, I used that in early beginnings with C^^

Comment: Looking at your code it seems you are using the for statement to delay the two operations you have to execute as neither doTask() and doSomethingElse() get the index as patameter

Comment: Actually, I'm working with the EntityFramework, I'm filling a lot of data in my Database (100000 by Example). Because that leads to an Out of Memory, I Save all Changes on each 1000th walkthrough and then I create a new instance of the context.. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with a modulo operator. Not sure about the C# syntax, but something like:

```
if(i % 1000 == 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (i != 0 && i % 1000 == 0)
```

It means if i mod 1000 is 0 (so on 1000, 2000, 3000, ...) but not on i == 0

Answer (score 4):

```
if (i != 0 && i % 1000 == 0) {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

`%` is the modulus operator, returning the remainder of a division operation. If the remainder is zero then you have a multiple of 1000. However you need to exclude 0 specifically because 0 is evenly divisible by 1000 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulo operator:

```
if (i % 1000 == 0) {
 // do something...
```

will do what you want.

It divides by the given argument (in this case, 1000) and gives you the remainder. In this case you're interested in a remainder of 0. See the doc for the modulo operator [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I'm *really* nitpicking here, and potentially answering a dead horse, but do this:

```
if(i%1000 == 999) ...
```

Instead of comparing to 0 and avoiding the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

use operator `%` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx